# windows standby

Tags: c++, windows

I have an app whose job it is to process data coming from a com port at either 2 or 60 second intervals.  Obviously, it doesn't make sense to have this app subject to standby.  Three things occur to me 1) tell windows periodically that things are happening that should delay standby 2) disable standby 3) detect that standby is configured and warn the user. IMHO, (1) would make the most sense.

So what do such application usually do?

How do I go about doing it c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SetThreadExecutionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) might help you -- specifically, the `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` flag "Forces the system to be in the working state by resetting the system idle timer."

Comment: A couple questions:  1) I assume I could simply issue a ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED every few seconds and that will keep the standby timer from going off 2) if I do ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED+ES_CONTINUOUS when I start something, how do I cancel it when I'm done? 3) Will the system cancel ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED+ES_CONTINUOUS when my app exits?

Comment: @Mike D: Yes, (1) is correct. For (2), you just specify `ES_CONTINUOUS` without other flags to cancel it. As for (3), I believe it will automatically clear since it's per-thread state.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the correct answer --

[Stop system entering 'standby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046/stop-system-entering-standby)